# Django MIDDLEWARE problem with RemoteUsers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    # ...
]
```

`ModelBackend` is used by the DRF Browsable API.

`RemoteUserBackend` is used by the frontend app.

If a user logs into the Browsable API, the frontend will send both the auth token and the session token. Both credentials are diferent django users.

`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` are suposed to work by order, but `AuthenticationMiddleware` goes first in MIDDLEWARE , it's mandatory.

A session-authenticated user gets wrong data in the frontend app. Django ignores remote user credentials. The user must logout from the browsable API.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record. I simply did a logout from the frontend at page load.